# Synonymize [struts2-jquery] to [struts2-jquery-plugin]

Tags: support, synonym-request

We should make [struts2-jquery](/questions/tagged/struts2-jquery) (211 questions) a synonym of [struts2-jquery-plugin](/questions/tagged/struts2-jquery-plugin) (4 questions).

To be extra clear: keep [struts2-jquery-plugin](/questions/tagged/struts2-jquery-plugin), the currently lesser used one.

They both appear to be asking about the same thing, and [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17177112/254830) is tagged with *both*.

## But why merge them *that* way around, if struts2-jquery is the most used?

Because **[Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)** is its actual name. We generally don't put a *-plugin* suffix on tags about specific plugins, but we *do* put that suffix in the tag's name when it's actually part of the plugin's name - we also do it for [jquery-forms-plugin](/questions/tagged/jquery-forms-plugin) and [google-earth-plugin](/questions/tagged/google-earth-plugin), among others.

It also clarifies this isn't just a plugin for jQuery (it's a Java plugin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, this is not a jQuery plugin but [a Struts2 plugin to use jQuery](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) and there are several `struts2-x-plugin` ([struts-json-plugin](/questions/tagged/struts-json-plugin), [struts-tiles-plugin](/questions/tagged/struts-tiles-plugin), [struts-junit-plugin](/questions/tagged/struts-junit-plugin) and so on).

So, maybe the first tag should remain.